# Deleting duplicates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL - How can I remove duplicate rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/sql-how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)

I have a table that's structured like this:

```
create table MnA
(id         int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY    not null,
symbol      nvarchar(4)                 not null,
direction   nvarchar(4)                 not null,
start_dt    nvarchar(5)                 not null,
end_dt      nvarchar(5)                 not null,
start_doy   int                         not null,
end_doy     int                         not null,
avg_price   int                         not null,
min_price   int                         not null,
max_price   int                         not null,
avg_percent int                         not null,
min_percent int                         not null,
max_percent int                         not null,
history     text                        not null,
percent_hit int                         not null,
aw_length   int                         not null,
diff        int                         not null,
date_change int                         not null)
```

I would like to delete rows that have similarities.

If the row has the same `symbol, direction, start_doy` and `diff` then I want to keep the one with the highest `avg_percent`.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Please show some sample duplicate rows and how you determine which row to keep. Also, specifying the *version* of SQL Server is useful.

Comment: Also not sure why the answer from @TimSchmelter was down-voted. It's as good a guess as any as to what breaks the tie...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DELETE target 
FROM MnA target INNER JOIN MnA temp 
     ON (target.symbol = temp.symbol 
         AND target.direction = temp.symbol
         AND target.start_doy = temp.start_doy
         AND target.diff = temp.diff
         AND target.id != temp.id 
         AND temp.avg_percent > target.avg_percent);
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4cc5/1)** (sqlfiddle).